# if your life is messed up, how do you improve it using islamic teachings?

Tags: quran, hadith

I know what I am asking is too much, I am not looking for life changing advises from people.  What I am looking for is a few Quran verses and hadith which says about how to improve your life if it's messed up with failures and problems or you don't know how to move forward in life from failures and problems.  I am pretty sure there must be advise or solution from Quran and hadith that if you have this issue or problem then do this for good life, just general life improving advise from Quran and hadith.

Comment: I don't know why my question is vote down, it's a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pray the five prayers. Pray the five prayers. Pray the five prayers. Pray the five prayers. Pray the five prayers.

In the case of sadness or need for consolation:

> O you who have faith! Take recourse in patience and prayer; indeed Allah is with the patient (2:153)

In the case of prevention of sins:

> Recite what has been revealed to you of the Book, and maintain the prayer. Indeed the prayer prevents indecencies and wrongs, and the remembrance of Allah is surely greater. And Allah knows whatever [deeds] you do. (29:45)

In the case of the afterlife:

> Indeed those who have faith, do righteous deeds, maintain the prayer and give the zakāt, they shall have their reward near their Lord, and they will have no fear, nor will they grieve. (2:277)

If you do not already pray the five prayers, it is vital that you start praying them. If you already pray them, it is better if you pray more of the Sunnah and Nafl prayers.